# jQuery count li-element and compare with each other. unsorted list in a unsorted list

Tags: jquery, html

I have something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul class="horizontal">
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="horizontal">
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<ul>
```

To count a li i use:

```
var CountLength = $('.horizontal li').length;
```

It is returning **5** but that's the total of all ul.horizontal elements. What i want to know is how do i get it to count the largest ul element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the set of `.horizontal` elements and compare the number of children each has with the current longest:

```
var longest = 0;
$(".horizontal").each(function() {
    var thisLength = $(this).children().length;
    if(thisLength > longest) {
        longest = thisLength;  
    }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/qFpFG/1/).